# PHP download client out of internet very slow

Tags: php, performance, download, delay, offline

I have a simple PHP page to download a pdf file. Here is the code

```
$file = "C:\\temp\\test.pdf";

header("Pragma: public");
header("Expires: 0");
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
header("Cache-Control: private", false);

header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"" . basename($file) . "\""); 
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary"); 
header("Content-Length: " . filesize($file)); 
readfile($file);
```

From another client i go with browser to the server address to download my file: http://192.168.23.33:8081/test.php
Then:

1. If the client is NOT connected to internet (connected only in LAN network) the download starts in 20-30 seconds
2. If the client is connected to internet the download starts in some milliseconds

What is the problem?
The server is Windows with Apache 2.4 and PHP 8. I've modified my hosts file because I read which it can be a dns solving problem:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
192.168.23.33 localhost 
::1          vmware-plugin
```

but this not solve the problem.
I need to have a fast download with a client not connected to internet.
Thank you very much

Matteo

Comment: DNS, and in this case the hosts file, is for mapping host names to IP addresses. Since you are not _using_ a host name to access the script in the first place, but go via the IP address directly, this is completely pointless.

Comment: It is probably not the script itself (have you _measured_ that, logged microtime at the beginning and end of your script, and compared the difference for both situations?), but how the client “finds” its way to the target server. But there’s really way too little info here, to say anything else.

Comment: Another strange thing is: this delay appears only when I download a file. Not if i browse a php page.